# Having trouble in Restkit 0.2 loading two different tables with the same Entity and different predicates

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

Here is the simplified version of what I am trying to do:

I have an application that uses UITabBarController as the root controller.
Inside two of the tabs I have a UINavigationController that contain a custom UITableViewController.

One of the Tableviews is to be used to display 'featured' items and the other is to display 'user' items.

The API endpoint for the first one is : /api/items/featured
and the other endpoint is : /api/items/user

I go through the whole process of setting up everything in my AppDelegate.m:

```
// Configure the object manager
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:API_SERVER]];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id":                     @"itemID",
 @"type":                   @"type",
 @"created_at":             @"created_at":
 @"field1":                 @"field1"}];

// User Descriptor
RKResponseDescriptor *userDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping pathPattern:@"/api/items/user" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:userDescriptor];

// Featured Listing Decriptor
RKResponseDescriptor *featuredDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping pathPattern:@"/api/items/featured" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

Then in the TableViewControls I have the following (substitute 'user' for 'featured' in the second tableview controller)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self loadItems];
}

- (void)loadItems {    
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/items/featured" parameters:nil 
        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    self.lastupdate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    } 
        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An Error Has Occurred" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    }];
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];
    self.managedObjectContext = managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Set predicate to only get Featured Listings
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"type like 'featured'"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Now this all works fine for the first tab (currently it returns 8 items, with type = 'featured', which are display in the table).

The problem comes when I switch to the second tab.  It currently only returns 1 item with type='user', and it crashes with :

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds for empty array with userInfo (null)

If I leave out the predicate on the 'user' tab, then the 'featured' tab works fine and the 'user' tab gets the 'featured' items in its table with the 'user' items on top'.

Since the code for the two tableview controls are identical, except for 'user' and 'featured', I'm at a loss on where the problem could be.

Answer (score 1):

When you create and configure your fetched results controllers, don't use a cache. Currently they are both using a cache of `@"Master"` and this will cause them to try and share information which is not appropriate because the fetch requests are different.

Comment: I have the same setup as darkrat but I'm using different cache names for the two view controllers and I still experience this issue. I've set the cache names to nil and it didn't help either.

Comment: How have you implemented the FRC delegate methods ?

Comment: I simply have `- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
 {
     [self.tableView reloadData];
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate change methods on the UITableViewController? I found a similar error when using RestKit/RKGist as a template and after removing those change methods, and removing the controller as delegate of them, this error disappeared. This worked for me as I wasn't interested in being notified about changes in this manner: I separated out the getter of the fetchedResultsController from the refetch-ing of the results and invoked the refetching in the success block of the respective RKObjectRequestOperation. Hope that helps!

EDIT

In my situation, I'm actually using two NSFetchedResultsController in one UITableViewController:

In my .h interface

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsOneController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsTwoController;
```

In the .m implementation:

A respective getter for each, that invokes the carved out refetch

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsOneController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsOneController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsOneController;
    }

    [self refetchResultsOneController];

    return _fetchedResultsOneController;
}
```

The refetch just contains the rest of your logic constructing the fetch request, entity description, sort, and fetch controller like:

```
- (void) refetchResultsOneController
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = ...;
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // set predicate for venue name
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: ....];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:200];

    NSSortDescriptor *distanceDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:...];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[distanceDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"SomeUniqueName"];
    self.fetchedResultsOneController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsOneController performFetch:&error]) {
        .. error handle...;
    }
}
```

Note the refetchers are distinct; different entities and different nspredicates, but same ManagedObjectContext.

And in the success block of the objectmanager action call the refetch, for resultsOne its a simple:

```
     [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"...the path for results one...", venueId] parameters:queryParams
                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                            [self refetchResultsOneController];
                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                        }
                        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                        }];
```

This works for me with the two NSFetchResultsController in one UITableViewController. Note I don't allow user action to edit/delete the objects in the fetchController (no two-way communication) - but I'm only interested in reading the data there and it'll always only be kicked off by a successful refresh to the remote server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would you mind posting some of that code? It would really help a lot, thank you!

Comment: How do you refresh your tableView? Do you use something like `- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller { [self.tableView reloadData]; }`?

Comment: correct however i call that in the success block of the objectmanager. sorry it was prior, i've edited above.

Comment: @sbonkosky did this end up working for you?  My project got book shelved and I haven't had spare time to verify that this works for me.  If its working for you then I'll go ahead and mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @darkrat I actually went about this an entirely different way without using a NSFetchedResultsController so I'm not sure if this answer is correct or not